# Migration from ASP.NET MVC to ASP.NET Core MVC - action model binding resulting null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

While migrating from ASP.NET MVC to ASP.NET Core MVC, I faced binding behavior troubles which I couldn't overcome.

I have this controller (for Razor, not API):

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SomeAction([FromBody] SomeModel model)
    {
        return Ok(model?.SomeValue);
    }
}

public class SomeModel
{
    public int SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

If I make a request to `/some/someAction` with a body of `{ "SomeValue": "6970" }`, I get a model equals null.

If I remove quotes `{ "SomeValue": 6970 }` I receive what I need, the model isn't null.

The project is big and I cant change all the js code to ints, also it could be a problem to change all models which expect int.

How I can let it work easily?

Comment: [Switch it back to using Json.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#use-newtonsoftjson-in-an-aspnet-core-30-mvc-project).

Comment: Thanks for response! How?

Comment: Follow the official instructions in the link I provided above, or see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57873403/model-binding-stopped-working-after-migrating-from-net-core-2-2-to-3-0-preview/57873496#57873496) that describes the same approach.

Comment: Yes, thank you, it works!

Answer (score -1):

Try to change your model from int to string and check if it works

Comment: Thank you for suggestions! As I said I don't want to change 1000 models, and I need int.